# How to get current hour in milliseconds format in java?

Tags: java, date

How to get current hour as a count of milliseconds since epoch?

Like if the time is 4:20 a.m.
Then how to get current hour in milliseconds so that it will represent 4:00 a.m.

Comment: Milliseconds since when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Java 8...

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MAY, 4, 4, 30);
ldt = ldt.withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
long millisSinceEpoch = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

The basic idea would be to take the "time" zero out the elements you don't want and convert the result to milliseconds...

## Also...

If you don't like typing, you could use...

```
ldt = ldt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

instead of `ldt = ldt.withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0)`

Comment: There's got to be something like Joda's `hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy()`, no?

Comment: @shmosel You're probably after [`LocalDateTime#truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

Answer (score 4):

You can try like that.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get current time
//set miliseconds,seconds,minutes to 0 so we get exactly the hour 
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
// This gets the time in milliseconds
long result=c.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: got it...can u explain what you doing in this ?

Comment: I tried to explain in edit. Remove the minutes/seconds/miliseconds from the current time and then get it in milliseconds

Comment: @AmitDas he is setting the calendar value to the current system time. This will also include the timestamp, which is why he sets the minute, second and millisecond to zero. What is left is the date + hour only which he then converts to a long value.

Answer (score 4):

```
Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
time = time / 3600000;
time = time * 3600000;
```

or a shorter version:

```
Long time = (System.currentTimeMillis()/3600000)*3600000;
```

Note: 3600000 = 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milisecs.

Rationale: when you do the first integer division by 3600000 you'll "lose" the information about minutes, seconds and milliseconds. However the result is in hours, not in milliseconds. To have the time back in milliseconds simply multiply by 3600000.

At the first sight it might look that dividing by 3600000 and multiplying 3600000 will be equivalent to "do nothing", but because of integer arithmetic the result is what you want (get rid of the minutes, seconds and milliseconds information).

Answer (score 1):

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.7, on a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object call the [`getMillisOfSecond`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html%23getMillisOfSecond--) method to return an `int`.

```
int millisOfSecond = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ).getMillisOfSecond() ;
```